# websocket connection via apache not established

Tags: apache, websocket

I configured httpd.conf for websockets, I am not able to establish a connection, I am getting “error reading status line from remote server”
Below are the errors and the configuration.

Configuration

```
<Location /socket.io/> 
ProxyPass http://172.27.38.93:9090/socket.io/
ProxyPassReverse http://172.27.38.93:9090/socket.io/ 
</Location> 
<Location /socket.io/1/websocket> 
ProxyPass ws://172.27.38.93:9090/socket.io/1/websocket 
ProxyPassReverse ws://172.27.38.93:9090/socket.io/1/websocket 
</Location>
```

Error.log

[Tue Feb 04 22:04:05.675146 2014] [proxy_http:error] [pid 7342:tid 47546562103616] (20014)Internal error: [client 10.20.136.193:52095] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 172.27.38.93:9090 
[Tue Feb 04 22:04:05.675183 2014] [proxy:error] [pid 7342:tid 47546562103616] [client 10.20.136.193:52095] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /socket.io/1/websocket/vTkhURqnBJdwnFRjbOt7

Pls let me know, what needs to be corrected.

Comment: Did you find a solution after all?